# Get 'OnDestroy' overrides nothing error when trying to shutdown textToSpeech - Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, overriding, text-to-speech, ondestroy

I haven't been able to find a solution to my issue, and I am sure I am doing something dumb I just can't figure out. I am working through a tutorial for Text To Speech right now, and I can't get the ovveride fun OnDestroy() to work. I get an error saying that it overrides nothing. Not sure what I am doing wrong. The code works fine if I remove that part of the code, but everything I have read online stresses the importance of including a shutdown to tts in the OnDestroy method. Any help is much appreciated.

```
package com.example.texttospeechdemo

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Toast
import com.example.texttospeechdemo.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import java.util.*



class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {

    private var tts: TextToSpeech? = null
    private var binding: ActivityMainBinding? = null


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding?.root)

        tts = TextToSpeech(this, this)

        binding?.btnSpeak?.setOnClickListener{view ->

            if(binding?.etTextToSpeak?.text!!.isEmpty()){
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,
                "Enter a text to speak",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
            }else{

                speakOut(binding?.etTextToSpeak?.text!!.toString())
            }


        }

    }

    override fun onInit(status: Int) {
        if(status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
            val result = tts!!.setLanguage(Locale.US)

            if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA ||
                result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED
            ) {
                Log.i("Error", "Language not found or isn't supported")
            }
        }else{
                Log.i("Error", "Initialization Failed")
            }


    }

    private fun speakOut(text: String){
        tts!!.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, "")

    }

    override fun OnDestroy(){


        if(tts != null){
            tts?.stop()
            tts?.shutdown()
        }

        super.onDestroy()
        binding = null

    }
}
```

Comment: `O` of `OnDestroy` must be in lowercase. See your super call `super.onDestroy()`

Comment: I knew I was doing something dumb! Rookie mistake right there :) Thank you so much!